# RestAssured, H2, SpringBootTest Transaction Management. Persisted data not available when calling REST Interface

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, h2, rest-assured

I wrote a simple SpringBootTest where I tried to read test data from a JSON file and insert it into the database in the @BeforeEach annotated method. When querying the data in the test method, I indeed find the data in the repository. When the REST interface is called via RestAssured and the corresponding method is executed, no data is found via the respository. However, when setting rollback=false in the test, I can find the data in the H2 database. Test code as follows:

```
package mypackage;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.get;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItems;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import mypackage.MessageEntity;
import mypackage.MessageRepo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallback;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = { "spring.main.lazy-initialization=true",
        "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:C:/mydatabase", "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=",
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create", "spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver",
        "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true", "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect",
        "spring.datasource.username=sa" })
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class MyWebServiceTest{
    @Autowired
    MessageRepo messageRepo;
    @LocalServerPort
    int port;
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeAll() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost/webservice";
        RestAssured.port = port;

        TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(this.platformTransactionManager);
        final List<MessageEntity> messages = setupMessages();
        transactionTemplate.execute((TransactionCallback<Object>) status -> messageRepo.saveAllAndFlush(messages));
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    @Rollback(false)
    void test() {
        System.out.println(messageRepo.findAll()); // successfully retrieves data
        get("/messages").then().assertThat().body("$", hasItems(67)).and().statusCode(eq(200)); // in the corresponding method of the WebService, no data is found
    }

    private List<MessageEntity> setupMessages() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        final String messagesString = Files.readString(
                Paths.get(Objects.requireNonNull(MyWebServiceTest.class.getResource("/messages.json")).toURI()));

        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(messagesString, new TypeReference<List<MessageEntity>>() {
        });
    }
}
```

I tried to persist the data in the @BeforeEach in different ways, tried flushing etc, but the data is not available when doing messageRepo.findAll() in the method called in the REST-Interface. I would expect the inserted data to be also available there. However, the data is available in the test method, but not at the REST endpoint.

Do you have any idea why this is happening and what I can try to get the desired result with my test data? Thanks!